# c++ segmentation fault when calling virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

I am doing a OOP practice in C++. I have a class called WARRIOR. It derives ICEMAN, NINJA, DRAGON, WOLF, LION. In WARRIOR class.

```
#ifndef WARRIOR_H
#define WARRIOR_H
#include "camp.h"
#include "weapon.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

extern int R;
extern int K;
class Weapon;
class Camp;
class Warrior
{
private:
  string warriorName;
  int warriorHealth;
  int warriorAttack;
  Camp* belongTo;

public:
  int pos;
  int warNo;
  void UseArrow(Warrior *w, Weapon *wp);
  void UseBomb(Warrior *w, Weapon *wp); 
  void UseSword(Warrior *w, Weapon *wp);
  void BrokeWeapon();
  void FightBack(Warrior *w, Weapon *wp);
  //void CopyWeapon(Weapon* wp);

  vector<Weapon*>weapList;
  Warrior(string s, int h, int att, Camp* c)
    :warriorName(s), warriorHealth(h),
    warriorAttack(att), belongTo(c),
    pos(0){}

  void SetHealth(int h){warriorHealth += h;}
  void SetAttack(int h){warriorAttack += h;}

  int WarriorHealth(){return warriorHealth;}
  int WarriorAttack(){return warriorAttack;}
    string GetName(){return warriorName;}
  void Equip(string s);

  bool Is_alive(){return warriorHealth > 0;}

  virtual int GetSpecial() = 0;
  virtual void March() = 0;

};

class Dragon : public Warrior
{
  double dragonMorale;
public:
  Dragon(int m, int h, int att, Camp* c, 
      string s = "dragon")
    :Warrior(s, h, att, c), dragonMorale(m){}
  ///
  void DragonRoar();
  void ChangeMorale(bool win);


  int GetSpecial(){return dragonMorale;}
  void March(){};
};

class Ninja : public Warrior
{
public:
    Ninja(int h, int att, Camp* c, 
      string s = "ninja")
    :Warrior(s, h, att, c){}

  virtual int GetSpecial(){}
  virtual void March(){}
};

class Iceman : public Warrior
{
public:
    Iceman(int h, int att, Camp* c, 
      string s = "iceman")
    :Warrior(s, h, att, c){}

  virtual int GetSpecial(){};
  virtual void March();
};

class Lion : public Warrior
{
int lionLoyalty;
public:
Lion(int loy, int h, int att, Camp* c,
      string s = "lion")
    :Warrior(s, h, att, c), lionLoyalty(loy){};
      //std::cout << WarriorHealth() <<"heal\n";}
void LoseLoyal();
void TransLife(Warrior *w);

  int GetSpecial(){return lionLoyalty;}
  virtual void March(){}
};

class Wolf : public Warrior
{
public:
Wolf(int h, int att, Camp* c,
      string s = "Lion")
    :Warrior(s, h, att, c){}
void Disarm(Warrior* w);
virtual int GetSpecial(){};

virtual void March(){}
};
#endif

void Iceman::March()
{
int temp = WarriorHealth();

if(temp < 10)
  SetHealth(-temp + 1);
else
  SetHealth(-9);

SetAttack(20);
}
```

my main function :

```
#include "camp.h"
#include "warrior.h"
#include "weapon.h"
#include "city.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int R;
int K;
int N;

int main()
{

    Warrior* ptr = new Iceman(10, 10, NULL);
    ptr->March();//segmentation fault here

    return 0;
}
```

Then, I ran the program through gdb.

```
Starting program: /home/linzhe/Working/cW/oop/8wk/wow/wow 
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file 
system-supplied DSO 0x7ffff7ffa000

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000004063bf in main ()
(gdb)
```

It seems that another virtual function

```
virtual int GetSpecial();
```

works just fine but not with

```
virtual void March();
```

Please help and thanks in advance. I use g++ to compile the program under Ubuntu 12.04.

//////

According to gdb, does it seem that the compiler fails to locate the exact virtual function?

/////
This morning, I tried to copy [warrior.cpp camp.cpp weapon.cpp city.cpp] to another folder and wrote a new main function to call Warrior::March(), and it worked. However, it just doesn't work at my original code......

Comment: I suspect that `10` is not a valid `Camp *`... Although I don't think that's probably what's causing the crash, because, at least in what you've posted, that value is never dereferenced.

Comment: I'm sorry that's my mistake. I was trying to new a DRAGON object but when I edited the code, I changed it back to Iceman without changing the constructor. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to the `Iceman` constructor is not valid:

```
Warrior* ptr = new Iceman(10, 10, 10, NULL); // Signature is (int, int, Camp*, [string])
```

So you are actually passing an int (10) as address of a `Camp` object and `NULL` for the `string`.

If - for example - you change your call to this constructor to

```
Warrior* ptr = new Iceman(10, 10, NULL);
```

it should work.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry that's a mistake. I was trying to new a DRAGON and then call March(). I have recompiled the code but it still doesn't work. Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: With your 'new' code above it is working for me - at least after adding a forward declaration for 'Weapon' and includes for 'string' and 'vector' - otherwise it is not possible to compile the code.Could you provide the whole code you are using? I think there are missing some lines at the top of your code.

Comment: I have added the complete 'warrior.h' and 'main.cpp'. This morning, I copied [warrior.cpp camp.cpp weapon.cpp city.cpp] to another folder and wrote a new main function to call Warrior::March(), and it worked. However, it just doesn't work at my original code......

Comment: Is the 'new' main function the same as the old one? If so, then I guess you used old object files during the link process.
If the 'new' function differs from the old one, then the difference between the two functions would be interesting.